# How to connect to a usb modem if there is no TTY?

Tags: usb, 15.04, usb-modem

I have a zte mf730m modem and I would like to connect and send some AT+ commands so that I can read and send SMS messages. The issue is that I can't find how to connect because even if it works(it connects to internet/3g) the device doesn't appear in /dev/tty*. I'm using 15.04(aka vivid) with systemd and I suspect that's the main issue. Is there any way that I can connect to the usb using the device id/vendor as provided by lsusb [0] or /sys/bus/usb/devices/XXX ?

[0] `Bus 004 Device 022: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?